# asp.net mvc error redirect to wrong location

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling

During a json request, the asp.net error redirect sends them to an incorrect path - it keeps looking for an Error.cshtml view under Home (the Home folder for views, as if it is trying to use my home controleler), when they are all under an Error folder/controller set up, which is clearly outlined in my config file:

```
   <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/Error">
     <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/NotFound" />
     <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/Error/Forbidden" />
   </customErrors>
```

Now, for a regular web page request, if there is an exception, it does redirect to the error controller, it's just when sending a request from jquery .ajax, it tries to look under the Home folder instead of Error.  Not sure how I can correct this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create this Action Method in your HomeController:

```
public ActionResult Error()
        {
            return View("Error");
        }
```

And

use

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Home/Error" />
```

in the web.config file

Location of error page (Error.cshtml): Views\Shared Folder

Comment: I could do that, but it should really be using the default redirect I already have, which is "~/Error/Error" - can the framework not handle using any other controller but Home for error redirects?  I believe we should be able to use whatever controller and view for that controller we want as long as it is in the web config, like I have.